# How to find the last non-digit in a string using python3

Tags: string, python-3.x

I use:

```
a_string = '00:00:02'
for char in reversed(a_string):
    if not char.isdigit():
        break
```

and "char" will be the last non-digit, but it feels hackish. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Yes, the list comprehension is my winner. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from a dedicated function? Pick any:

```
# regex
print (re.findall(r'(\D)\d*$', a_string)[0])

# list comprehension
print ([x for x in a_string if not x.isdigit()][-1])

# filter
print ([x for x in filter(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), a_string)][-1])
```